# Force Gridlayout to have x amount of columns and square cells

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using the GridLayout to try to create a grid of square elements, so no matter the width of the screen or the number of children there is always x number of columns and their height is the same as their width (square). Here is a picture of what I want:

[image: Grid 3/5]

[image: Grid 12/15]

I don't want the children to stretch at all and I want it to warp at the end of a line. This is what I have so far:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:padding="@dimen/drawerPadding"

        app:columnCount="5">

        <ImageView
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But as you can see there are not 5 columns and the children aren't square. Can I force it to have 5 columns and keep the children square? The content is dynamic so I won't know how many children it will have, but I can add styles to the children, for example, if there is the CSS equivalent of `25vw`.

[image: Grid Layout]

#### Update

I've been able to get columns evenly arranged by making the first row contain 5 textviews with a `layout_columnWeight` of `10000` and a `layout_height` of `0dp`. Then all the remaining elements that I want to add I give a `layout_columnWeight` of `0.001`. It works but it seems very hacky, so I'm still looking for a better solution. I still have not been able to get the elements to appear square.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        app:columnCount="5">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="10000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="10000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_columnWeight="10000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_column="3"
            app:layout_columnWeight="10000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_column="4"
            app:layout_columnWeight="10000" />

        <ImageView
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_columnWeight="0.001"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_columnWeight="0.001"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_columnWeight="0.001"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Grid with columns correct]